# ListView not shown when trying to go back

Tags: android, listview

I have tested my app with the emulator and everything works as expected. now im debugging the app via usb debugging. This is when i get this issue.  I have a **ListView** in my app. When the user press a List Item it starts a new activity. My issue is, after the user press the back button, the **ListView** is not generated again. I just a blank activity.Even if i restart the app, when i go to the activity that contains the **ListView**, it wont generate the **ListView**. The only way to fix this is to clear the data of my application via my phone settings. What is causing this issue? Why is it working well with the emulator and not with my phone? (Im using a Xiaomi Mi4) any help would be much appreciated.

CustomListAdapter

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Guide> guideItems;

public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Guide> guideItems) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.guideItems = guideItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return guideItems.size();
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return guideItems.get(location);
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);       
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customrow, parent, false);

    TextView ngno = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_ListNgno);
    TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_ListName);
    TextView email = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_ListEmail);

    // getting movie data for the row
    Guide g = guideItems.get(position);

    ngno.setText(g.getNgno());      
    name.setText(g.getName());     
    email.setText(g.getEmail());

    return convertView;
    }
}
```

This is the activity that implements the ListView.

```
public class ViewGuidesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = ViewGuidesActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private List<Guide> guideList = new ArrayList<Guide>();
private ListView listView;
private CustomListAdapter adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_guides);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, guideList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    // Showing progress dialog before making http request
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();

    // Creating volley request obj
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(AppConfig.URL_GET_GUIDE_LIST,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Guide guide = new Guide();
                            guide.setNgno(obj.getString("ngno"));
                            guide.setEmail(obj.getString("email"));
                            guide.setName(obj.getString("name"));


                            // adding movie to movies array
                            guideList.add(guide);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, error.toString());
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            hidePDialog();

        }
    });

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    this.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
            Guide newGuide = guideList.get(position);
            String email = newGuide.getEmail();
            String ngno = newGuide.getNgno();
            //System.out.println(email);

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GuideDetails.class);
            i.putExtra("email", email);
            i.putExtra("ngno", ngno);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    hidePDialog();
}

private void hidePDialog() {
    if (pDialog != null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog = null;
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    menu.getItem(1).setVisible(false);
    menu.getItem(2).setVisible(false);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



}
```

Comment: Have you tried to output some log before adding items to your list? Just to make sure the code is running...

Comment: Go to settings -> developer options -> Don't keep activities. It's keep turn off

Comment: my Code is running. Because i get what i expect in my emulator. But isnt working on the phone. enabling Don't keep activities doesnt solve my problem.